# BpMemoryHeap issue with app that involves soundpool

Tags: android, soundpool

I have created an app that involves about 600 small ogg files. Total around 15MB. Each file will have avg. of 6 seconds sound. This is not a game app but learning app for children.

I tried loading the sounds on Media player. It works fine once and when continuously played I end up getting no sound. It is blank.

So I tried sound pool option. Sounds are played only after the it loads to soundpool loader. hence I tried loading the sounds in the start of the app. So it takes about 30 seconds to load the sounds and main screen shows up after that (I am loading the sounds using Async in background and progress bar is shown in the front).

This setup works just fine for about 450 ogg files when I add one sound more than 450 I get heap error on loading couple of sounds and app force closes with the below error:

```
 02-27 07:13:02.614: I/Choreographer(27172): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 02-27 07:13:11.012: E/IMemory(27172): binder=0x56f0c430 transaction failed fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error 2147483646)
 02-27 07:13:11.012: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.012: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56f0c430), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.020: W/dalvikvm(27172): threadid=37: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d75930)
 02-27 07:13:11.153: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=818, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.153: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56f09e80), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.403: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=972, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.403: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56f09988), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.450: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=873, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.450: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56f0a500), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.520: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=954, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.520: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56efbde8), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.614: W/dalvikvm(27172): threadid=35: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d75930)
 02-27 07:13:11.677: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=903, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.677: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56f09b30), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.716: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=978, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.716: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x5d99add0), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number) 
 02-27 07:13:11.747: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=941, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.747: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56efb710), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
 02-27 07:13:11.809: E/IMemory(27172): cannot dup fd=991, size=1048576, err=0 (Too many open files)
 02-27 07:13:11.809: E/IMemory(27172): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x56efaa90), size=1048576, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
```

How do I fix this issue? most of the issue on Heap is about database cursor not with soundpool.

if this can't be solved what is a work around on using soundpool when I have 600 sounds to load?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some way to break up the file loading into logical segments? Do all 600 need to be loaded at once? For instance, if you have three modes of play, could you load just the sounds needed for each mode once it's selected?

Comment: I tried doing it.. For e.g. I have 3 modules. Every time I click on each module I used load required sounds but then I had wait for the sounds to load and then screen come up. Which is not actually user-friendly right?

Comment: Honestly, neither is a 30 second startup time, especially for a kid's game. alex's answer below is probably a good solution for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

With this many files you're going to want to lazy load them and dump ones that haven't been used in a while.

There's an [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) in Android that will help you there.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can you give an idea on what should I do with  LRUCache and Soundpool?

Comment: Use LruCache to store you sounds instead of Soundpool. Stuff that's less used will be evicted and stuff that's used a lot will stay there

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html this is about Bitmaps but the principle's the same

Comment: but the soundpool is used to play the sounds. I can't use media player. If I use LRUCache for loading the sounds.. how to play it?

Comment: Why can't you use MediaPlayer?

Comment: Reason: As explained the top When I use mediaplayer. It works fine once and when continuously played I end up getting no sound. It is blank.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps you can use LruCache and SoundPool together. Keep track of the ids of the sounds when they go in and remove the least used when you're sailing close to the OoME wind.

Comment: I will check on it and get back today! BTW: What OoME Window?

Comment: Sailing close to the wind is an English expression that means you're close to disaster.

Comment: Alex: After deep thought on your logic. I figured out it wont be good idea to release unwanted sounds reason because I don't want the users to always load the sound when they are loading different modules in the app at the same time.